# How can I connect to mongodb in getStaticProps function(next.js)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I'm new to next.js. In the following code, I'm rendering the home page on the server and populating the props object through a file named "products.json". I have successfully done that. now the next step for me is to populate the props object, in the function named `getStaticProps`, through MongoDB.

CAN I CONNECT TO MY MongoDB USING MONGOOSE? if not, please guide me with the best approach to do so.

```
import fs from "fs/promises";
import path from "path";
import Link from "next/link";

const Home = (props) => {
  const { products } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Lists of product:</div>
      <ul>
        {products.map((product) => {
          return (
            <li key={product.id}>
              <Link href={`/${product.id}`}>{product.title}</Link>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  console.log("Re-Generating...");
  const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), "data", "products.json");
  const jsonData = await fs.readFile(filePath);
  const data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
  return {
    props: data,
    revalidate: 10,
  };
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either write a `seed.js`  file to populate but I thing you want to run in automated fashion during build time.

```
// assuming that you already properly wrote this model. I anemd it Products
const Products = require("../models/products");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

export async function getStaticProps() {
  ongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/products", {})
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    .then((con) => console.log("connected to db"));
  // this data should match with Products schema
  const products = require("/data/products.json");

  const seedProducts = async () => {
    try {
      // if you dont delete you will have repeated data over and over
      await Products.deleteMany();
      await Products.insertMany(products);
      // use this if you run a separate seeder.js file. otherwise your next.js app will exit
      //process.exit();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      process.exit();
    }
  };
  seedProducts();
// you always have to return something in this function
return {
    props: {
      something: "something",
    },

 };
}
```

I do not know what is the use case of this but it is not efficient. Because in a dev environment, `getStaticProps` run with every request, it acts like `getServerSideProps`. every time you refresh your page, this function will be executed and you will send queries to the database to delete and write. This will cause network latency. Bether way is write the above function in a file, `seed.js` located in some level with `package.json` and then run `node seed.js` from the terminal

Comment: thanks, Yilmaz. I just want to fetch a list of products from MongoDB. I see that I can use the mongoose library. Your last comments about network latency are profound. I'm new to coding. I want to ask a few things about this.

Comment: if I just use mongoose to connect to my DB and fetch data inside getStaticProps with the intention of getting my index page pre-rendered in the server, would you consider this approach inefficient?

Comment: @abrarzahid getStaticProps executed only once when you build the app. With incremental Static regeneration you can revalidate it after a certain time. but for e commerce you always want to show the fresh data to the user, so you should be using `getServerSideProps`

Comment: @abrarzahid Normal aproach would be you write a controller on server side. you define a route and write the logic when this route gets request that logic willl be executed. So inside `getServerSideProps` you should be sending an axios request to that controller and get the data.

Comment: @abrarzahid In either case you would be making a get request to the database.  But in your case, when you populate database, you make delete and write requests. that is why seeder should be running in a separate file and you would be runnigni only once and your db will get the data

Comment: getStaticProps usually won't be used for the index page. Because  in index page you should always be sending the freshest data. Better approach would be adding a caching layer to the application but i think since you are in early stage of programming, you can just ignore the caching for now